# How to set DIV's width based on CSS indexes

Tags: html, css, pocketgrid

I have 6 floated DIVs in two rows. I use [PocketGrid](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/#creating-rows-and-columns-the-cool-way) as CSS framework (in particular its "[*automatic rows*](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/#automatic-rows-in-real-life)" feature) and I would like to size each one using CSS indexes and not specific class name.

I tried it in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfg40qd1/) but even if first 3 blocks (first row) are sized correctly, next 3 ones are not.

```
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-child(1n) {
  width: 40%;
}

.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 20%;
}

.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-child(3n) {
  width: 40%;
}
```

How to set `.block:nth-child(...)` in order to have:

- 1st and 4th blocks with 40% width
- 2nd and 5th blocks with 20% (and so on)

Comment: are you looking for odd and even? `:nth-child(even)` and  `:nth-child(odd)`

Comment: No, in general, each block has an indepent width. Here, casually, first and thirs have the same but in general, as I wrote, I would like to set a different width for each block, obviously, in case of 100 DIVs, first, fourth, seventh will have the same, and similarly second, fifth, eighth, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly,all you need to do is change your CSS to the following:

```
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-child(3n+1) {
  width: 40%;
}
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-child(3n+2) {
  width: 20%;
}
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-child(3n+3) {
  width: 40%;
}
```

Side note: your br tags should be `<br/>` for jsfiddle to interpret them correctly.

Comment: This solution works!!! just a question: is a little counter-intuitive reasoning with "negative" values. Is possible to obtain the same result with "positive" values ad in Maioman solution (that anyway does not run for the moment)?

Comment: Sure you can! See my edited answer. (Old habit to go backwards for compatibility in an old program I used to use)

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want ...

```
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-of-type(3n+1),
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-of-type(3n){
    width: 40%;
}
```

... `3n` for every 3rd .block and `3n+1` for every .block after the 3rd block (which includes the first block) and ...

```
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-of-type(3n+2){
    width: 20%;
}
```

... `3n+2` for the middle .block (second .block after the 3rd .block on each row, which includes the second .block in the first row).

This pattern will work for every row, no matter how many rows you add, as long as you want/have 3 "columns".

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/26101p20/1/)

Comment: Thank you - I updated the CSS that I copied and pasted form your original fiddle (that was sloppy of me not to) so that you are only targeting `.block:nth-of-type` and it doesn't matter if you use line breaks ... `:nth-child` will count any children of the parent and mess with the math a little (and break the pattern).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CSS will not allow complex identifiers like you require.

You are trying to format the following children:

```
1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12
```

The only way I could think of doing it is to add a spacing div to ensure an even number of divs/line, then assign odd and even children a different style.

http://jsfiddle.net/pfg40qd1/2/

EDIT: Alternatively, if you know that there will always be three/row just...

```
<div class="row">Blocks</div>
```

...and format the blocks with respect to the row div.

Comment: Result that you posted is effectively what I need  but If I have to use "spacer divs", so I would use class name on each one, avoid to add non semantic divs.
In some way, I already used complex identifiers, (in clear:none, clear:left) descendants, so I think that is possible in some ways

Comment: Seems like @jaunt has cracked it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a syntax like `nth-of-type(4n+1)` , `nth-of-type(4n+2)`, `nth-of-type(4n+3)` and `nth-of-type(4n+4)`,

I suggest the use if `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` because it's suites better in your case

```
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-of-type(4n+1) {}
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-of-type(4n+2) {}
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-of-type(4n+3) {}
.sintesi-offerta > .block:nth-of-type(4n + 4) {}
```

[check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfg40qd1/3/)

Comment: Mhmmm perfect fot `nth-of-type` suggestion but yours proposal about `4n+X` does not run...

Comment: @LucaDetomi in your fiddle it looked like you had a four cycle.. nevermind